# Symfony not found static files (images, js, txt)

Tags: symfony

How can Symfony deliver static files without bootstrapping/executing the framework?

For example: if some requests are failing by the webserver(images, js files are not found or something like this) then the framework tries to solve the route. Of course this does not exists.

Is there a way to avoid this or blacklist these extensions?

[image]

Comment: in your dev-environment, you get more extensive error messages, in prod this is a simple 404 page. I'm not quite certain what you mean by your other questions though. The Webserver can't know which urls symfony will handle, unless you explicitly tell it to, apart from that, webservers will deliver static files from the web root (public directory in symfony) if configured correctly. ...

Comment: What webserver are you using? This is the webserver's job. You can configure it so it will **not** pass certain URLs to the PHP process (e.g. anything ending in jpg, css, gif, etc).

Comment: I am using the symfony's webserver. I know it's the job of the webserver to handle this, maybe the question a bit confusing, as I want to improve my dev environments speed.

Comment: Symfony web server is only meant to be used during development. You should not worry about this kind of thing while developing.

Answer (score -1):

It could be a cache problem.

**If it is :**

If it is a cache problem, you could try to clear the cache on the symfony console with `cache:clear`. If it doesn't work you could try to remove the ressources in the general folder, leaving the original ones in your bundle, and running `assetic:dump` and `assets:install`.

**If it isn't**

Regarding the "remove-symfony-routing" thing, I don't know if it's possible, but **it should not done anyways**.

What you're asking is to be able to access, from the client side, any file on the server, which constitutes **a major security breach**.

This could allow the client to get any file on the server, meaning he could get his hands on your javascript or php files which most of the time contain valuable information (such as how your app works or even deadlier : global passwords and config values)

What you could do to access resources from the client would be a route that points to a controller function that could output to browser the file you're looking for, provided that it has an extension you'd be ok to share. For example you could allow any image file but forbid code files such as php or javascript.

EDIT: Or yeah, configure your webserver correctly. 2 simple answers while I was typing :D